# How do I import a script?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file that contains my main function and calls my other file "parser_utils.py" for all the functions needed to run the program. I'm just looking to import my script "parser_utils.py" in my main function "Parser.py" but it hangs when I try to run the script. I did try adding parser_utils.FunctionName every time a function from the other script is called, but still no luck.

Main script trying to call my utility file

```
#/usr/bin/python3 

import parser_utils
import sys

def main():
```

There are the results when I try to run the program.

```
import-im6.q16: not authorized `parser_utils' @ error/constitute.c/WriteImage/1037.

import-im6.q16: not authorized `sys' @ error/constitute.c/WriteImage/1037.

./parser.py: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `('

./parser.py: line 6: `def main():'
```

Comment: For sure add at least a `pass` statement in the `main()`, otherwise that's invalid syntax. Not sure about the parser_utils, it seems like that's a specific error. Please add more information to the question if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurs when there is something wrong with your shebang lines. The line you have is missing an exclamation mark i.e.

change this: `#/usr/bin/python3` to this `#!/usr/bin/python3`